# Json data is not showing in datatable using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, datatables

I am using ASP.NET; I am getting the data from the backend as expected, but it is not showing in the web page using a datatable.

Web page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee";
}

<h2>Employee List</h2>

<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>EmployeeId</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Position</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

JavaScript portion of code (jQuery)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                processing:true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Employee/GetList",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "success": function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg.data);
                    },
                    "failure": function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    },
                    "error": function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                },
                "columns": [
                    { data: "EmployeeId" },
                    { data: "Name" },
                    { data: "Age" },
                    { data: "Position"},
                ]
            });
        });
```

Here is the response I am getting from the backend. This is the data I copied from Netword -> Response tab against the endpoint I call to fetch the data

```
{
    "data": [
                { 
                  "EmployeeId": 1,
                  "Name": "Dhruv",
                  "Age": 23,
                  "Position": "Full Stack Developer"
                },
                {
                  "EmployeeId": 2,
                  "Name": "Soni",
                  "Age": 21,
                  "Position": "DBA"
                },
                {
                  "EmployeeId": 3,
                  "Name": "Mike",
                  "Age": 24,
                  "Position": "Frontend Developer"
                },
                {
                  "EmployeeId": 4,
                  "Name": "Bob",
                  "Age": 20,
                  "Position":"SRE"
                }
            ]
}
```

I am trying to get the data from database and show it to the user using a datatable. I am successfully getting the response back from the database, but the data is not showing inside the table. And I can't figure it out why....

Comment: Could you please share your backend code? How you are sending from your controller? As Json?

Comment: You must avoid using the `success` option the DataTables `ajax` option. See the official documentation for [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) which explains why - and what to do instead. This may not be sufficient to get your code working (there may be other additional problems), but it is necessary.

Comment: Hello, have you tried the updated solution? Do you need any further assistance on this?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:3**

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetList()
        {
            var empList = new List<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee(){ EmployeeId = 1, Name = "A", Age = 19, Position = "Engineer-I"},
                new Employee(){ EmployeeId = 2, Name = "B", Age = 20, Position = "Engineer-II"},
                new Employee(){ EmployeeId = 3, Name = "C", Age = 21, Position = "Engineer-I"},
                new Employee(){ EmployeeId = 4, Name = "D", Age = 22, Position = "Engineer-III"},
               

            };
           
          return Json(new { data = empList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**Note:** You even can directly `return Json(new { empList })` in that case, in your `HTML-Ajax` you only have to write `return msg;` not `msg.data`

View:

```
<h2>Employee List</h2>
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>EmployeeId</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Position</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                "ajax": {
                    "type": "GET",
                    "url": "/DatatableInAnotherWay/GetList",
                    "dataSrc": function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg.data);
                        return msg.data;
                    }
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "employeeId" },
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "age" },
                    { "data": "position" },

                ]
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** I am returning as `return Json(new { data = empList });` so I would receive response as `msg.data`. Check the response in your browser console as below:

[image]

Importantly, be sure about the `column case` as you can see I am getting it as `lower-case` so I bind them as like this`"data": "employeeId"`. As you are saying you are getting in Upper-Case as `EmployeeId` you should then bind as `"data": "EmployeeId"`

Final Output:

[image]

**Special Note:**
Remember these words forver, If you want to be a great programmer, you must concentrate on :

1. Debugging
2. Code readability
3. Self reading/teaching attitude

**Update:2**

If you still want to persist with your code: You could do as following:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                "ajax": {
                    "type": "GET",
                    "url": "/Employee/GetList",
                    "dataSrc": function (msg) {
                        return msg;
                    }
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "EmployeeId" },
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "Age" },
                    { "data": "Position" },

                ]
            });
```

Issue on your code:

You were defining the `column` in worng way: you should do it in following way:

```
"columns": [
                        { "data": "EmployeeId" },
                        { "data": "Name" },
                        { "data": "Age" },
                        { "data": "Position" },
    
                    ]
```

Update:2 Output:

[image]
**Update:**

Based on your updated question, its clearly seen that you are `ajax` calling pattern is incorrect. How your `msg.data` would be bounded into your `"columns":` no way. Please try my updated code. Just copy and paste.

> I am successfully getting the response back from the database but the
> data are not showing inside the table. And i can't figure it out why?

It's because of your row definition in your `columns` within the datatable.

You would define all of your data members in lower case - like

```
"columns": [
               { data: "employeeId" },
               { data: "name" },
               { data: "age" },
               { data: "position"},
           ]
```

**Note:** UpperCase  `EmployeeId`, `Name` etc  in jQuery datatable are causing parsing issues. In addition, please follow the `$.ajax({});` calling format as per my demo for better code readability.

Complete example:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Position</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Employee/GetList",
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#myTable').DataTable({
                        data: response,
                        columns: [
                            { data: 'EmployeeId' },
                            { data: 'Name' },
                            { data: 'Age' },
                            { data: 'Position' }
                        ]
                    });
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: public ActionResult GetList()
        {
            using(DBModels db = new DBModels())
            {
                var empList = db.Employees.ToList<Employee>();
                return Json(new {data = empList}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }

Comment: Hi @Md Farid Uddin Kiron I tried your code but I am still not getting the data inside the data table

Comment: You can now check the updated answer, try to place them accordingly, check your browser log details. If you still encounter issue, feel free to let me know.